# Swift 3 Value of type 'Any' has no member 'valueForKey'

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, swift3, xcode8, any

I am writing a test program with Core Data using Swift 3.0 in Xcode 8. Problem is that when I try to receive any data from NSManagedObject like this:

```
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Entity")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
do {
    let entityTableInCoreData = try newPrivateQueueContext.fetch(request)
    for i in entityTableInCoreData {
        if let a = i.valueForKey("b") as? String {
            print(a)
        }
    }
} catch {
}
```

the line

```
if let a = i.valueForKey("b") as? String {
```

marked with error

> Value of type 'Any' has no member 'valueForKey'

So question is how to get from type Any a single record data?
P.S. if it is possible, without casting to AnyObject type because it is leading to this

```
if let a = (i as AnyObject).value("b") as? String {
```

which also has a error:

> Cannot invoke 'value' with an argument list of type '(String)'

And I want to do it in proper way.
Thank you!

UPDATE

I found a solution (thanks to Vadian), but I doubt it is right one:

```
    do {
    let entityTableInCoreData = try newPrivateQueueContext.fetch(request)
    for i in entityTableInCoreData {
        print("Record")
        //print(i)
        if let a = i as? NSManagedObject {
            print("a: \(a.value(forKey: "a"))")
        }
    }

} catch {
}
```

I am still searching for a right way to do this.

Comment: No, it is also a error:

Comment: Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: Where to do this? fetch(request) as [String: AnyObject]

Comment: As I understand entityTableInCoreData is just an array of NSManagedObjects. So I just need to take data from it.

Comment: `fetch` returns `[Any]`. You have to downcast the type to `[NSManagedObject]` or `[NSFetchRequestResult]` or if you're using a subclass of `NSManagedObject` – which is recommended – to `[<Name Of Subclass>]`

Comment: Can you check update of my answer? Is it you were talking about?

Comment: Basically yes, but I meant to append `as! [NSManagedObject]` to the `fetch` line. The optional binding `if let a = i` is not needed because in this case it's guaranteed that the return type is `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: Ok, thank you! But I will leave it is an optional, just to be 100% protected. But you think it is rightful and proper way to read data from Core Data and NSManagedObject?

Comment: Yes it is. Regarding the optional binding you are 100% protected.`fetch` can return an array of `Dictionary` or an array of `NSManagedObject` depending on the request. If you don't pass explicitly  `return value is dictionary` you get 100% `NSManagedObject`, That's one of the few cases where optional binding is misused because it's redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch` returns `[Any]`. You need to downcast the type to the actual type, in this case `[NSManagedObject]`.

```
let entityTableInCoreData = try newPrivateQueueContext.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject]
```

The forced downcast is safe because according to the fetch request it's guaranteed that the return type is `NSManagedObject`.